# Single Sign on java

Tags: java, jboss, single-sign-on, weblogic-10.x, josso

I am looking for a single sign on framework in java which supports Weblogic 10.3 and Jboss 4.2.2 and 5.1. JOSSO supports weblogic and jboss both but I am having lot of problems in weblogic (Session expiry issues, its not working on root context, different workflow for jboss and weblogic etc.). I am tired of JOSSO now. Please suggest me a stable SSO framework which works in jboss and weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

What about an alternative like OpenID?

Comment: I have already spent significant amount of time on JOSSO and can't afford to do R&D at this stage..thats where I am looking for the help who have already used SSO FW in weblgic 10.3 and JBOSS 4.2.2 and 5.1..

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use [Spring security](http://www.springsource.org/features/security) you can choose from several SSO options including [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas), [Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com) and OpenId. A great benefit of Spring is that it sits at the application level (i.e. inside the WAR/EAR) and therefore eliminates many of the platform specific "gotchas" like the ones you are experiencing.

Of course if you aren't able to use Spring my solution is of little use! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com) includes a standard Java EE servlet filter which certainly works on JBoss (I have used it). I haven't tried it on Weblogic though.